# How to use PowerShell to create client secret?

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm kind of new in the web development. I developed an ASP .NET Core Web application that is registered in the Azure portal of my organization. This web application is using Microsoft Graph API, so it needs the client secret to work.

Well, my problem is that the UI in azure portal don't let me create a client secret that never expires. I read that you can create the client secret using the PowerShell. How does it work? Once created, will this secret be visible in the "app registration" of the azure portal? Do I need to execute the code in a specific repository in PowerShell? Never used this tool, so I'm kind of lost.

Feel free to redirect me in the good direction!

Comment: Using client secrets which won't expire is a very bad practice security wise.

Comment: @bluuf They want as less maintenance as they can. I'm just an Intern but I agree with you ahah. Well, I could let it slip and force them to renew or create a new secret each 24 months

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the client secret from the Remote PowerShell or from the PowerShell in azure cli.

- You need to install Azure AD modules if you want to connect to azure ad from remote PowerShell.
- Run the below Install command in PowerShell in Admin mode.

```html
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
```

- Here is the reference document to install [Azure AD modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/connect-to-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide#step-1-install-the-required-software)
- Here are the list of commands to create an New App registration in the Azure active directory & followed by client secrets.

```html
connect-AzureAD
    $azureADAppReg = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName NewStackTest -AvailableToOtherTenants $false -IdentifierUris 'https://local host'
    New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -CustomKeyIdentifier PrimarySecret -ObjectId $azureADAppReg.ObjectId -EndDate ((Get-Date).AddMonths(6))
```

- Once you create the Client Secret from the PowerShell, it will automatically reflect in the Azure portal & it will be visible under  client & secrets in App registrations.

Comment: I was kind of stressed to try it, but it worked like a charm. I'll expose them to this reality and they will make a choice of how it's going to go from there. I'll never thank you enough for your concise explanation. Have a great day sir!

Comment: @JulienTurcotte Glad I could help, can you please accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future